# Can ultrasounds generate lift?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, lift, ultrasound

Imagine a plate, the bottom side is flat and the top has dimples (or other structures that increase surface area)
If we vibrate it ultrasonically left and right wouldn’t it experience lift because of different air pressures on each side due to turbulent air flow on the top side?

Comment: Are you already assuming there is airflow over the plate?

Comment: @UVphoton no I’m not assuming that